# Why does my button in my DataTable pass 0 each time it is clicked and not the Id it should be passing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

I want my button to pass the Id of the element in the row. I can see that the button contains the Id of the element in the row by using developer tools in the browser. However, when I press the button, 0 is passed every single time. The buttons are in a jQuery DataTable.
Below is the DataTable code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <!--CSS for DataTables-->
    <link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>

<body>
    <h1>All Accounts</h1>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div>
        <table id="allAccounts" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Organization</th>
                    <th>State</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a asp-action="Index">Back to Home</a>
    </div>


</body>
</html>


@section Scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#allAccounts').DataTable(
                {
                    "responsive": true,
                    "ajax": {
                        "url": "/api/User/GetUsers",
                        "dataSrc": ""

                    },
                    "columns": [
                        { "data": "FirstName" },
                        { "data": "LastName" },
                        { "data": "Organization" },
                        { "data": "State" },
                        {
                            "data": "Id",
                            "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                                return "<button class='btn btn-danger' style=margin-right:5px; onclick=DeleteUser(" + row.Id + ")>Delete</button>"

                            }
                        }
                    ]
                });
        });
      
        function DeleteUser(data) {
            $.ajax({
                "type": "POST",
                "url": "/api/User/Delete",
                "data": data
            })
        }
    </script>
}
```

The Delete method found in the User Controller is below:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Delete(int data)
{
    

    return RedirectToAction("DeleteUserConfirm", "Home", data);
}
```

The Home Controller method is below:

```
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult DeleteUserConfirm(int id)
        {
         
            return View(_userRepository.GetUser(id));
            
        }
```

The GetUser() works and I can see that it gets the object from the database. However, the DeleteUserConfirm page is not being displayed. I have also tried using ViewData.Model = _userRepository.GetUser(id); return View(); which also did not work.

I know it is not best practice to redirect to another controller. However, at this point I would just like the button to pass the correct data. Zero is being passed to the User Controller, so I know the Ajax url is passing the data to the correct method. However, the data that is being passed is incorrect. Any suggestions on how to get the button to pass the Id of the element in the row would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller method is missing [FromBody]

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Delete([FromBody]int data)
{    
    return RedirectToAction("DeleteUserConfirm", "Home", data);
}
```

and Ajax-call is missing

```
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
```

and you'll have to use this for data

```
JSON.stringify(data)
```

and your redirect should be like this

```
return RedirectToAction("DeleteUserConfirm", "Home", new { id = data });
```

Comment: When I added [FromBody] to my controller method I received an HTTP 415 error, which is for an unsupported media type client error

Comment: Hi. You are also missing 
`contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'`
in your Ajax-call. That will fix the 415-error.

Comment: I've tried adding the contentType as well and I get a HTTP 400 error.

Comment: Please set a breakpoint inside your controller method and check if your code hits the controller.

Comment: It does not hit the controller

Comment: Found the problem, your data format is wrong too, you'll need to use JSON.stringify(data)

Comment: Now the data successfully passes to the controller as an int. When it is then redirected to the DeleteUserConfirm method in the home controller, the data that is passed is always 0.

Comment: More fixes required: `return RedirectToAction("DeleteUserConfirm", "Home", new { id = data });` Not sure how your next method looks like, but hopefully, you get the idea :-)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!! I have only one more problem/question I promise! Your fix to pass the data from the User Controller to the Home Controller worked! However, now the page that is supposed to display that data is not rendering. The page was working before I made these other changes. I have updated my original post to include the DeleteUserConfirm method. Again I really appreciate your help!

Comment: My pleasure :-)  In `public IActionResult Delete(int data)`, I guess you are deleting the user. So when you are trying to fetch user from db inside `public IActionResult DeleteUserConfirm(int id)`, it is no longer there. You can either display a generic message like "User deleted", or "User #id deleted". In APIs, it is normal to return nothing on delete, so I guess both solutions will be appropriate. BR